# Why exactly does copper have a higher melting point than zinc?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, enthalpy, transition-metals, melting-point

It is said that copper has a higher melting point than zinc because of the d electrons in copper being involved in metallic bonding. However, copper has no unpaired electrons in its d subshell just like zinc. How can we explain this observation ?

Comment: why was this question closed? just curious

Comment: the question seems clear to me, why does copper show a higher melting point than zinc even though both have fully filled d subshells. (not sure about the validity of the premise)

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati This q. was completely rewritten and might be reopened, but copper *does* have an unpaired electron.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/melting-and-boiling-points-of-transition-elements/4815#4815

Comment: @Mithoron Copper does have an unpaired electron, but in its s subshell. The reasoning is given based on the electrons in its d subshell, which makes it confusing.

Comment: @wonderingwhy read the link sent by mithoron and your doubt may be clarified.

Comment: @GauravSaiMaddipati I did read the link and the other answers. It explains the anomalous behaviours of Cr,Mn and Tc and that is understandable. My doubt is strictly limited to the statement which says that 'the d electrons in copper are involved in metallic bonding due to which it has a higher melting point than zinc'.

Comment: Could you give a source for that statement?

Comment: There is a multiple choice question going around and that is chosen as the correct answer. For example : https://www.sarthaks.com/2987888/the-melting-point-of-copper-is-higher-than-that-of-zinc-because